# Reference properties files in WAS v8.5

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml, properties-file

We've purchased a thirdparty servlet that references a properties files from web.xml (i.e. d:\projects\MyProp.Properties) . Since moving to Websphere v8.5, we can no longer have the properties file on a logical drive and have to place it inside our app's project. However, we do not have access to the code to the servlet that open/references the properties file. I've tried changing the properties reference to \WEB-INF\MyProp.properties but it's not found during server startup.

Is there a project reference I can use in web.xml allowing the servlet to open the file?

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution - because we have a NAS location where we place all the .jars that our WAS v8.5 compatible applications can access, I placed the properties file there, updated the path to the file in web.xml and viola, the servlet was able to access/open/read the properties file!

\is2-cifs.domainname.com\sbl_prod$\propertiesfolder\MyProp.Properties